# A pyramid in a prism - How to prove that this angle is right?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, angle

[image]

I have been struggling to prove that angle CBE in this solid is a right angle. First of all, I thought about the possibiliy that angles AED and BEC are congruent, because they "share" the same vertex and AD = BC, this does not work however, because triangles BCE and ADE have different areas. Now, I am stuck. Could you shed some light on this problem for me?

Comment: Write out the components of the vector defined by $\overbar{BC}$ and by$\overbar{BE}$ then do a dot product and see that it is $0$.

Comment: David G. Stork, 
Sorry, but we haven't done the dot product or vector equations yet, it's a high-school level problem.

Comment: Intuitively: you can see that $\angle CBF$ and $\angle CBA$ are both right angles, so $BC$ is perpendicular to the plane $ABF$, which also includes the point $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector defined by $BC$ is $\{0,1,0 \}$ and the vector defined by $BE$ is $\{ -1,0, 1 \}$.  The "dot product" of two vectors is the sum of the products of their paired components, here:

$0 \cdot (-1) + 1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 1 = 0$.

This means the vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it.

Is there a way to prove it without using the dot product, straight from the diagram?

Comment: $BE$ lies in the plane perpendicular to $BC$, and is hence itself perpendicular to $BC$.

Answer (score 3):

$CB$, by construction, is orthogonal to plane $ABFE$, thus it is orthogonal to any line in this plane, in particular to line $BE$.